# Why does Windows 8 change the drive letters?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

On Windows 7, the partition that had Windows 7 was C:. I had 2 other partitions D: and E:. I installed Windows 8 on E. When I boot into Win8, E is shown as C. And the one which had Windows 7 installed is shown as E. But there is no change when in the drive letters when I boot into Win7.

**WIN7**
`C: (Contains Win7)`
`D:`
`E: (Contains Win8)`

**WIN8**
`C: (Contains Win8)`
`D:`
`E: (Contains Win7)`

Why this change? And won't it create problems?

Comment: The letters don't really mean anything, they're just sort of an alias for the location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't create any problems except some confusion for someone. This changes is because, Windows assign drive letter `C:` on the drive, where it itself is installed. So, For Windows 7, `C:` is the partition it installed into, the same case for Windows 8.

Note that: Drive letters don't depend on partition numbers, though it may be seems so, because it is a tradition to install Windows on the first partition. I have Windows 7 installed 7th partition, and in Windows it is shown as `C:`.

Comment: Of course one can also change the drive letter if you want.  The default behavior is as you describe.  So it is only logical a fresh installation of Windows 8 would have the default behavior.

Comment: This "will" create problems if you have hundreds of scripts and apps to migrate that use hard coded paths!